# Google cloud speech api hang-up

Tags: api, google-cloud-platform, speech

When I testing speech API it's hang-up long time no response, what am I missing?

1. I have passed the translate API test with proxy
2. The test code same like https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/reference/libraries

Comment: You may have already done this, but have you set your credentials file path? `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=...`. Have you also enabled the API via the GCP console already?

Comment: I tried to replicate your scenario with the python client libraries and everything was ok. Can you please specify the request that you are doing as well the programming language?

Answer (score 0):

Network services can hangup for various reasons. There could be security measures as well as simple network problems. You can try local speech service if you need realtime response.